# Issue with color picker button being an svg and the element being changed also svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg, fill, color-picker

I am attempting to make a color picker where the button or color options are SVG elements, and when clicked, they change the fill color of another SVG. I'm not too sure why the code isn't working. I made sure to target the correct class, and as well made sure the class was in the section of the SVG that contains the fill style... I don't know why my code is wonky in Stack but here is a link to my CodePen https://codepen.io/maddylobb/pen/oNormML Any and all help is appreciated!

```js
var colorArray = ["#8ecae6", "#219ebc", "#023047", "#ffb703", "#fb8500"];
var colorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".colors-svg");
var content = document.querySelector(".colors-svg-main");

function buidPickerOptions() {
  colorButtons.forEach((button, i) => {
    // set the fill color of each button
    button.style.fill = colorArray[i];


    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // set the fill color from the button that is clicked
      content.style.fill = colorArray[i];
    })
  });
}
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #219ebc;
  height: 100vh;
  //position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  #color-change-element {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    #s-7 {
      max-height: 400px;
    }
  }
  #select-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    width: 200px;
    #select-bottom {
      height: 40px;
      ul {
        background-color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        li {
          list-style: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 30px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          width: 30px;
        }
      }
      #colors {
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  <div id="color-change-element">
    <svg id="s-7" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79 76">
          <g clip-path="url(#clip0_187_4)">
            <path d="M0 0h79v76H0z"/>
            <path class="color-svg-main" d="M40.39 5.987c.645-1.918 1.278-4.159 3.167-4.975a3.71 3.71 0 0 1 2.89.018c.845.418 1.8 1.419 2.295 4.77.496 3.352.047 6.078-.36 8.676-1.678 10.564-1.119 12.164-.25 13.096.49.522 1.16 1.357 4.56 1.32 7.11-.078 14.25 1.14 21.322.391a3.696 3.696 0 0 1 2.35.424 4.248 4.248 0 0 1 1.443 1.713c.319.69.445 1.45.367 2.206-.305 2.303-3.064 3.59-6.266 5.045a38.866 38.866 0 0 1-8.528 2.64c-2.73.468-5.947.675-8.55 1.622-1.034.336-1.871 1.119-2.505 1.999-.364.541-.533 1.798-.557 3.575-.032 2.539.717 3.547 2.162 8.091.469 1.855.568 2.238.966 3.498.49 1.45 1.023 2.798 1.738 4.151a22.785 22.785 0 0 1 2.142 8.493 2.313 2.313 0 0 1-.51 1.756c-.823.8-2.435.328-2.987.169-4.2-1.22-8.15-9.012-14.983-16.397-1.464-1.58-3.44-3.547-6.181-3.707-1.431-.082-2.736.34-4.638 1.43-5.449 3.104-8.213 7.284-13.99 11.734-.727.556-2.34 1.76-4.334 1.582-.19.004-2.289-.228-2.925-1.597-.724-1.551.767-3.653 1.682-4.942 7.65-10.806 9.189-13.277 10.174-16.288.717-2.173 1.622-5.08.46-7.999-.609-1.515-1.664-2.76-5.742-5.41-8.222-5.343-12.67-5.967-13.247-9.28a3.786 3.786 0 0 1 .94-3.339c1.344-1.204 3.545-.333 9.09 1.46 4.312 1.394 8.59 2.675 13.465 3.017a8.332 8.332 0 0 0 4.749-.741c1.892-.982 2.774-2.6 3.803-4.527 3.985-7.494 5.98-11.25 6.788-13.674Z" fill="#F366CC" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
          </g>
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip0_187_4">
              <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h79v76H0z"/>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
            </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="select-container">
    <section id="select-top">
      <h1>Select One:</h1>
      <!-- <div>
                    <button class="selected">Colors</button>
                </div> -->
    </section>
    <div id="select-bottom">
      <section id="colors">
        <ul>
          <li><svg id="s-7" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79 76">
                            <g clip-path="url(#clip0_187_4)">
                              <path d="M0 0h79v76H0z"/>
                              <path  class="color-svg" d="M40.39 5.987c.645-1.918 1.278-4.159 3.167-4.975a3.71 3.71 0 0 1 2.89.018c.845.418 1.8 1.419 2.295 4.77.496 3.352.047 6.078-.36 8.676-1.678 10.564-1.119 12.164-.25 13.096.49.522 1.16 1.357 4.56 1.32 7.11-.078 14.25 1.14 21.322.391a3.696 3.696 0 0 1 2.35.424 4.248 4.248 0 0 1 1.443 1.713c.319.69.445 1.45.367 2.206-.305 2.303-3.064 3.59-6.266 5.045a38.866 38.866 0 0 1-8.528 2.64c-2.73.468-5.947.675-8.55 1.622-1.034.336-1.871 1.119-2.505 1.999-.364.541-.533 1.798-.557 3.575-.032 2.539.717 3.547 2.162 8.091.469 1.855.568 2.238.966 3.498.49 1.45 1.023 2.798 1.738 4.151a22.785 22.785 0 0 1 2.142 8.493 2.313 2.313 0 0 1-.51 1.756c-.823.8-2.435.328-2.987.169-4.2-1.22-8.15-9.012-14.983-16.397-1.464-1.58-3.44-3.547-6.181-3.707-1.431-.082-2.736.34-4.638 1.43-5.449 3.104-8.213 7.284-13.99 11.734-.727.556-2.34 1.76-4.334 1.582-.19.004-2.289-.228-2.925-1.597-.724-1.551.767-3.653 1.682-4.942 7.65-10.806 9.189-13.277 10.174-16.288.717-2.173 1.622-5.08.46-7.999-.609-1.515-1.664-2.76-5.742-5.41-8.222-5.343-12.67-5.967-13.247-9.28a3.786 3.786 0 0 1 .94-3.339c1.344-1.204 3.545-.333 9.09 1.46 4.312 1.394 8.59 2.675 13.465 3.017a8.332 8.332 0 0 0 4.749-.741c1.892-.982 2.774-2.6 3.803-4.527 3.985-7.494 5.98-11.25 6.788-13.674Z" fill="#F366CC" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
                            </g>
                            <defs>
                              <clipPath id="clip0_187_4">
                                <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h79v76H0z"/>
                              </clipPath>
                            </defs>
                              </svg></li>
          <li><svg id="s-7" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 79 76">
                          <g clip-path="url(#clip0_187_4)">
                            <path d="M0 0h79v76H0z"/>
                            <path  class="color-svg" d="M40.39 5.987c.645-1.918 1.278-4.159 3.167-4.975a3.71 3.71 0 0 1 2.89.018c.845.418 1.8 1.419 2.295 4.77.496 3.352.047 6.078-.36 8.676-1.678 10.564-1.119 12.164-.25 13.096.49.522 1.16 1.357 4.56 1.32 7.11-.078 14.25 1.14 21.322.391a3.696 3.696 0 0 1 2.35.424 4.248 4.248 0 0 1 1.443 1.713c.319.69.445 1.45.367 2.206-.305 2.303-3.064 3.59-6.266 5.045a38.866 38.866 0 0 1-8.528 2.64c-2.73.468-5.947.675-8.55 1.622-1.034.336-1.871 1.119-2.505 1.999-.364.541-.533 1.798-.557 3.575-.032 2.539.717 3.547 2.162 8.091.469 1.855.568 2.238.966 3.498.49 1.45 1.023 2.798 1.738 4.151a22.785 22.785 0 0 1 2.142 8.493 2.313 2.313 0 0 1-.51 1.756c-.823.8-2.435.328-2.987.169-4.2-1.22-8.15-9.012-14.983-16.397-1.464-1.58-3.44-3.547-6.181-3.707-1.431-.082-2.736.34-4.638 1.43-5.449 3.104-8.213 7.284-13.99 11.734-.727.556-2.34 1.76-4.334 1.582-.19.004-2.289-.228-2.925-1.597-.724-1.551.767-3.653 1.682-4.942 7.65-10.806 9.189-13.277 10.174-16.288.717-2.173 1.622-5.08.46-7.999-.609-1.515-1.664-2.76-5.742-5.41-8.222-5.343-12.67-5.967-13.247-9.28a3.786 3.786 0 0 1 .94-3.339c1.344-1.204 3.545-.333 9.09 1.46 4.312 1.394 8.59 2.675 13.465 3.017a8.332 8.332 0 0 0 4.749-.741c1.892-.982 2.774-2.6 3.803-4.527 3.985-7.494 5.98-11.25 6.788-13.674Z" fill="#000" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
                          </g>
                          <defs>
                            <clipPath id="clip0_187_4">
                              <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h79v76H0z"/>
                            </clipPath>
                          </defs>
                            </svg></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var colorArray = ["#8ecae6","#219ebc","#023047","#ffb703","#fb8500"];
var colorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".color-svg"); // edited colors to color
var content = document.querySelector(".color-svg-main"); // same here

function buidPickerOptions(){
    colorButtons.forEach((button,i) => {
        // set the fill color of each button
        button.style.fill = colorArray[i];


        button.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            // set the fill color from the button that is clicked
            content.style.fill = colorArray[i];
        })
    });
}

buidPickerOptions() // you should call the function
```

Comment: PS: "I made sure to target the correct class, and as well made sure the class was in the section of the SVG that contains the fill style..." you can use ```console.log(target)``` to check targets and you can also check if a function is running

Answer (score 1):

First, `console.log()` is your best friend when debugging js. If you log `colorButtons` you will see an empty array. Instead of `document.querySelectorAll` you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("colors-svg")`. However, you do not have a single element with the class name "colors-svg".

Second, you seem to be mistaking class names with ids. Every id should be unique, but there are multiple elements with the same ids.

You also should not nest your css properties as shown above. Unless you are using some sort of framework that allows such behavior, then you should at least separate things as follows:

```css
#content {
    background-color: #219ebc;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#s-7 {
    max-height: 400px;
}

#color-change-element {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#select-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    width: 200px;
}
#select-bottom {
    height: 40px;
}

ul {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 30px;
}

#colors {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
```

Last, when adding event listeners you need to make sure that you use the correct `this` scope. Otherwise all buttons will behave like the last button in your loop. In order to use the correct `this` value you need to replace your arrow function with a regular `function(event) {}` syntax. I also do not think your .forEach loop is formatted correctly, but I think this is enough to work with for now.